# Unique solution of an ODE with a bounded positive right-hand-side

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, reference-request, integral-equations

Consider the initial value problem $$\dot x(t) = F(t,x), \quad t \in (0,T)$$ with given initial datum $$x(0) = x_0 \in \mathbb R.$$ More precisely we consider the integral equation $$x(t)=x(0)+\int_0^t F(s,x(s))ds.$$

$F$ may be discontinuous, but let us assume that $$0 < m < F(t,x) < M.$$

The common counter-examples to uniqueness (or existence) of ODEs (or their associated integral equations) seem to rely on $F$ switching sign, or being close to $0$, and my intuition is that the lower bound $m<F(x)$ should imply existence of a unique solution.

**Question 1:** Is it true that there exist a solution under the assumptions above?

**Question 2:** Can we also prove uniqueness?

Comment: There are many issues here, what does a solution mean in the above context?

Comment: There is not even existence without continuity of $F$.

Comment: As a general reference for uniqueness results, I would like to mention the book ``Uniqueness and Nonuniqueness Criteria for Ordinary Differential Equations'' by Agarwal and Lakshmikantham.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to both questions is no. The most general existence theorem I know is [Carathéodory's existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem). It requires
that $F(t,x)$ is continuous in $x$ for each fixed $t$, measurable in $t$ for each fixed $x$ and a boundedness condition similar to the one of the question (but $m$ may be negative). Without a minimum of conditions of $F$, the function $s\to F(s,x(s))$ may not even be measurable.
The positivity of $m$ does *not* imply uniqueness as a simple variant of the classical counterexample shows. Consider
$$x'=1+2\sqrt{|x-t|}, x(0)=0.$$
The transformation $z=x-t$ shows that it is quivalent to $z'=2\sqrt z, z(0)=0$.
Two solutions are, for example, $x_1(t)=t+t^2$ for $t\geq0$, $x_1(t)=t$ otherwise and $x_2(t)=t$ for all $t$. Actually, the initial value problem, as the classical one, has a two-parameter family of solutions. So clearly, $F(t,x)\geq1$ for all $t,x$, but there is no uniqueness.

Comment: Does the situation change if you consider $F$ autonomous, that is independent of time?

Comment: @Riku Yes. If $F(x)$ is continuous and positive in a neighborhood of $x_0$ then the unique solution is given by $$\int_{x_0}^x\frac1{F(y)}dy=t$$ for small $t$. Here it is used that the integral defines a continuous strictly increasing and therefore invertible function.

Comment: I meant autonomous, bounded as in the question and possibly discontinuous

Comment: @Riku It seems sufficient that $F$ is measurable and bounded as in the question to carry out the above proof.

Comment: Ok. What about the uniqueness in the autonomous case?

Comment: @Riku As I said, the formula gives the unique solution.

Comment: But I don't think that one can prove the uniqueness by the classical argument, which requires Lipschitz continuity. How would you do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113556/discussion-between-helmut-and-riku).